# How do I add multiple associated objects to a parent in its parents form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im on Rails 4. I am making a subscription model where users build what products they want in their subscription. I have many models here, but the ones I feel are important in my question are a `Product` model, a `Subscription` model, and a `SubscriptionItem` join model. The products are set in the db, and a user can choose how ever many they want to add to their subscription, hence the join model.

My Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscription_items
    has_many :subscriptions, through: :subscription_items
end
```

My Subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :plan
  has_many :subscription_items
  has_many :products, through: :subscription_items
  validates :name, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscription_items
end
```

My SubscriptionItem join

```
class SubscriptionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :product
end
```

In my new subscription view, I want users to simple check off check boxes to choose what products they want included...

I currently have...

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <h3>Choose your items</h3>
        <div class="products">
            <% @products.each do |product| %>
                  <%= f.fields_for :subscription_items do |p| %>
                    <%= p.label :product_id, product.name.titleize %>
                    <%= p.check_box :product_id, product.id %>
                  <%= end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My new and create methods in my `Subscriptions` controller

```
def new
    @plans = Plan.all
    @subscription = Subscription.new
    @products = Product.all
    @subscription.subscription_items.build
end

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @subscription = @user.subscriptions.build(sub_params)
    if @subscription.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your subscription has been created."
        redirect_to @user
    else
        flash[:alert] = "There was a problem and your subscription could not be created."
        render "new"
    end
  end
```

And my strong params...

```
def sub_params    
    params.require(:subscription).permit(:name, :plan_id, subscription_item_attributes: [:id, :product_id])
end
```

When I try and create a Subscription, the subscription_items are not created. Any suggestions?

Comment: subscription_item_attributes should be subscription_items_attributes in params require, note 's' in item

Comment: Thank you, Of course it was something simple. Now when I make a subscription though, it is making a SubscriptionItem record even if the checkbox is left blank

Comment: Include [`reject_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) : `accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscription_items, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['product_id'].blank? }`